# can we encode/decode image stored in static resource using EncodingUtil

Tags: unit-test

Can we encode/decode image stored in static resource using EncodingUtil? I want to write test class for 'upload photo' functionality, for that I need get image stored in document. Hence I'm trying to get test image stored in static resource as document body, but I am unable to do that.

Comment: what did you try? when you say decode, do you mean just get the bytes of the image, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A Document body is a field of type [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm). So for the purpose of a test you can create a Blob on the fly:

```
Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Fake Body');
Document d = new Document(
        Name = 'Fake Name',
        FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
        Body = b
        );
insert d;
```

and later on assert:

```
Document dd = [select Body from Document where Id = :d.Id];
System.assertEquals(b.toString(), dd.Body.toString());
```

Obviously the Blob here isn't an image, but that is irrelevant as the code is just proving that some bytes can be stored and retrieved.

This approach avoids having to have a static resource that is used only in a test.